# How to create a normal function inside jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is the following method of function creation inside jQuery plugin correct ?

```
(function($){

 $.fn.sample = function() {
     test();
 }  

function test() {
   alert('Inside jQuery plugin');
} 
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is "correct" in that it's valid, and `test` is only accessible inside the wrapping function:

```
// Immediately-invoked function expression, creates a new execution context
(function($){

    // Expose a property on jQuery.prototype, available to all jQuery instances
    $.fn.sample = function() {
        test();
    }  

    // "Private" function, only accessible inside the enclosing context
    function test() {
        alert('Inside jQuery plugin');
    } 
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: @Sandesh: Have a look at the jQuery Documentation to see how a basic plugin is built: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/